# Check if object is an event in JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events, cross-browser

I have a function that might either be called explicitly or when an event fires.  If it's triggered by an event, I need to ignore a function parameter that might otherwise have a useful value.

Is there a reliable, cross-browser way I can check whether an object is an event?

We've been using this, but realized it doesn't work in IE7 since `Event` is undefined:

```
var view = {
    save: function (data) {
        if (data.constructor === Event.constructor) {
            // It's an event.
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the "poor man's" way would be to just check for the existence of a certain method that all `Event` objects have - regardless of how they are created:

```
if (!(typeof data.altKey == "undefined")) {
  // it's an Event
}
```

**EDIT**

Since preventDefault isn't accepted in some versions of IE I've changed the solution to use a different property, really any common property should work just fine.

Comment: `preventDefault` is undefined in early versions of IE

Comment: And if you're supporting those versions of IE then you are supporting unsupported software. IE 6+ supports `preventDefault` (and it isn't even supported by Microsoft any longer). Sorry, but that -1 is a bit harsh.

Comment: IE9 is the earliest version to support `preventDefault`.

Comment: Fair enough, my bad, but the same idea would work with a different property. Will update.

Comment: As long as OP doesn't define the same property in a non-event it should be OK.

Comment: +1 In light of recent edits this seems to be the only way.